# How to kill powershell process via cmd? Unified Remote app

Tags: powershell, cmd, process, taskmanager

I have started using Unified Remote app on my Android device. 
This app has a lot of features including quick actions which lets me run cmd remotely and add command line to it. It's a widget and I just need to press a button in the widget to start a process. Everything seems to be fine, I press a button and a powershell script starts. 
This is a command line in cmd:

`Powershell.exe -File C:\my_path\user\myscript.ps1`

The problem is when I try to kill a powershell process, it just doesn't work.

I have created a new button to stop a process and this is a command-line via cmd:

```
taskkill /IM "powershell.exe" /F
```

My aim is to make a button which stops a script from running.

Comment: Does it work if you open a CMD window yourself on the computer and then enter the command?

Comment: It does work when I do it manually.

Comment: Have you tried `killall -9 powershell`

Answer (score 0):

`killall -9 powershell` will kill all the processes that have the string powershell in their name.

Comment: For asking a clarification question please use your commenting privilege. For answering please avoid asking a question, even a rhetoric one. Otherwise you risk being flagged as "Not an answer". I also recommend to try for a more assertive answer, i.e. avoid "try".

Comment: @Yunnosch, I'm wondering how you found this answer. Did you just find this answer and post your comment or do you search for answers with a try in their name and paste a response manually or do you have a bot you wrote to do it for you? I'm wondering because you have a really high reputation and I'm curious how users reach that level. Your feedback was helpful, and I have commented and changed my answer... but Im not sure if I should remove it completely. Where might I find guidance on that in the future?

Comment: I am using a bot, which I think most marshals use; did not write it however. My reputation is only midlevel, there are users with 10 or 100 times that much. Getting it required constant tedious hard work, especially on my slow specialty tags. Your answer now looks fine, though in order to get upvotes you probably want to add some explanation how it is supposed to solve the problem. I.e. why is this going to help, while OPs attempts did not. Especially I am not sure whether OP wants to kill a specific task, while your answers code looks like it might kill "all" of them.